# How to solve "TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined" in Firebase with Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a Document in my Firestore db by using Cloud Functions. Also using Postman to send the folowing POST:

```
{
"firstname": "TestFirst2",
"lastname ": "TestLast2",
"email": "test2@test.com"`enter code here`
}
```

This is the Function I'm trying to execute:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.addUserReq = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
   const firstname = String(request.data.firstname)

   const col = admin.firestore().collection(`users`)
   col.add({
       firstname: firstname,
       lastname: request.data.lastname,
       email: request.data.email})
       .then(snapshot => {
       const data = snapshot.data()
       return response.send(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
       console.log(error)
       response.status(500).send(error)
    })
})
```

And this is the ErrorMessage:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined
at exports.addUserReq.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:14:34)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:735:7
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:718:11
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

I already searched in the Firebase docs, but didn't found something. How can I define the param "firstname" to avoid the errorMessage?

> Update:
>   This is a snippet of the index.js of my web app that is causing the same results as the request with Postman.

```
function save() {

 var userFirstname = document.getElementById("firstname_field").value;
 var userLastname = document.getElementById("lastname_field").value;
 var userEmail = firebase.auth().currentUser.email_id;

 var addUser = functions.httpsCallable('addUserReq');
 addUser({
   "users": {
       "firstname": userFirstname,
       "lastname": userLastname,
       "email": userEmail
     }
   }
   ).then(function(result) {
   var result = result;
 }).catch((err) => {
   alert(err)
 });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
exports.addUserReq = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
const firstname = String(request.data.firstname)
```

into this:

```
 exports.addUserReq = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
const firstname = String(request.body.firstname)
```

Firebase uses the `express` framework to be able to do http requests.

According to the docs:

> Used as arguments for `onRequest()`, the [`Request`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) object gives you access to the properties of the HTTP request sent by the client, and the Response object gives you a way to send a response back to the client.

The request object of the express framework has the property `body` that contains the data submitted:
http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but now I get the following error: `Error: Argument "data" is not a valid Document. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value (found in field firstname).` It references to the ´data´-Object I try to use in `add()`. 
But now the `console.log(firstname)` works and the value is `undefined`. :(

Comment: change this `request.data.lastname` into `request.body.lastname` and `request.data.email` into `request.body.email`

Comment: No. But in mine. I still don't get a value with my request. It's always undefined. Is my request with Postman not right?

Comment: I already changed them into `request.body.lastname` and `request.body.email`.

Comment: const firstname = request.body.firstname this gives u undefined?

Comment: Correct. And it only works with the `String(...)` arround them. Without I get the same `TypeError` as before.

Comment: Hey, I made it to write into Firestore, but value is `undefined`. The error got away, after I surrounded the other const's with `String(...)`.

Comment: can you show me how you are sending the request in the code?

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvMXX34kixuMkeg1dWFXxO2_e4JlqQ

It's a link to a screenshot of my Postman config.

Comment: I get in Postman `Error: could not handle the request`, if it didn't worked and a `{}`, it it worked. 
I got a little web app, that I start locally. It's giving me the same results as Postman. I will upgrade the code on my post.

Comment: ohhhhh now I saw your front end code, I think you need to do `request.body.users.firstname` try it and tell me

Comment: Also do `console.log(request.body)` immediately after this `exports.addUserReq = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {` and tell me what you get

Comment: I get the TypeError from before :( 
And the `console.log(request.body)` gave me the first time `<Buffer 7b 0a 20 20 20 20 22 66 69 72 73 74 6e 61 6d 65 22 3a 20 22 54 65 73 74 46 69 72 73 74 34 22 2c 0a 20 20 20 20 22 6c 61 73 74 6e 61 6d 65 20 22 3a 20 ... >` and after that just `{}`.

Comment: I didn't changed anything on the client side. But after trying out a bunch of `console.log()`s with the `request`, I found out, that the data was in `request.body.data`. So with `reqeust.body.data.user.firstname` it worked. 
Thanks for your advice with the `console.log()` and `request.body.users.firstname`. That helped to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes always use console.log it helps to see the output

Answer (score 0):

```
     col.add({
      // firstname: firstname, ==> where is this firstname comming from?,
firstname:request.data.firstname,
lastname: request.data.lastname,
       email: request.data.email})
       .then(snapshot => {
       const data = snapshot.data()
       return response.send(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
       console.log(error)
       response.status(500).send(error)
    })
```

Comment: I tried different things and declared a const one line under the export-line. But that's not working either.

Comment: unfortunately not.